# Download speed lower than it should be?

Tags: internet-connection, wifi-driver, internet-speed

I recently installed the Windows 10 Creator's Update and ever since my download speed is lower than it should be. (It used to be around 30mbps, now it's around 10-5)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DLdn.png]

This has been happening with my laptop only. (MSI GL62)

I've updated my internet driver, and that didn't seem to solve anything.

Help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "internet driver"?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified how you updated the driver for the network card,
or what is your card,
but you are not the first on our site to complain of degradation
of all sorts after installing the Creators Update.

The solution that usually worked is actually to delete the driver and
to let Windows 10 install its own.

You should run Device Manager, then right-click on your network adapter and
choose the option of `Uninstall`. When it's finished, reboot and let Windows
install its own driver.